# Как упростить код включения/отключения компонентов через GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как проще и красивей записать следующий код :

```
RTSCameraController tempRTSCameraController = transform.GetComponent<RTSCameraController> ();
if(tempRTSCameraController) {
    tempRTSCameraController.enabled = true;
}
MouseLook tempMouseLook = transform.GetComponent<MouseLook> ();
if(tempMouseLook) {
    tempMouseLook.enabled = false;
}
ScenarioCamera tempScenarioCamera=transform.GetComponent<ScenarioCamera> ();
if(tempScenarioCamera) {
    tempScenarioCamera.enabled = !valueBool;
}
CameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager tempCameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager = transform.GetComponent<CameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager> ();
if(tempCameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager) {
    tempCameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager.enabled = !valueBool;
}
CameraRotateAroundManager tempCameraRotateAroundManager = transform.GetComponent<CameraRotateAroundManager> ();
if(tempCameraRotateAroundManager) {
    tempCameraRotateAroundManager.enabled = valueBool;
}
RTCCamera tempRTCCamera = transform.GetComponent<RTCCamera> ();
if(tempRTCCamera) {
    tempRTCCamera.enabled = valueBool;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `MonoBehaviour` сам по себе имеет методы `GetComponent`, не нужно для этого каждый раз вызывать `this.transform`
2. Сегодня Unity полностью перешла на `.NET 4.x`, так что стоит использовать его нововведения, а конкретно - Null Propagation. Но для этого свойство `enabled` нужно обернуть в расширение класса `MoniBehaviour`:
3. Зачем изначально вешать компоненты, которые будут отключены по флагу? Делайте `if(flag) this.AddComponent<T>();`

---

Что там за логика в коде в целом, я не знаю, поэтому приведу код с улучшениями из пунктов 1-2:

```
public class NullPropagation : MonoBehaviour
{
    void SomeMethod(bool valueBool) {    
        GetComponent<RTSCameraController>()              ?.SetActive(true);
        GetComponent<MouseLook>()                        ?.SetActive(false);
        GetComponent<ScenarioCamera>()                   ?.SetActive(!valueBool);
        GetComponent<CameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager>()?.SetActive(!valueBool);
        GetComponent<CameraRotateAroundManager>()        ?.SetActive(valueBool);
        GetComponent<RTCCamera>()                        ?.SetActive(valueBool);
    }
}


public static class Utility {
    public static void SetActive(this MonoBehaviour obj, bool active) {
        obj.enabled = active;
    }
}
```

Comment: GetComponent<...> () ?. Вопросом  компилятор проверяет существует объект или нет ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Это Null Propagation. По сути, знак вопроса проверяет, что слева от него **не** null, если там действительно не null, то выполнится код справа от знака вопроса. Если же null, то код справа не выполнится. В общем, компактная запись `if(obj != null) {...}` :)

Comment: спасибо большое ! У знаю много нового для себя , благодаря вам)

Comment: @IvanTriumphov в этом и идея ;)

Comment: Как подключить class Utility и метод класса SetActive В другом файле ?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "подключить в другом файле"? Класс Utility можно поместить в другой файл, все это никуда не нужно подключаться, методы-расширения из публичного класса работают во всей сборке.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101508/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).